# Not able to run AndroidViewClient

Tags: androidviewclient

I am get the all the Id's of the current screen without using the Source.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333936/android-get-id-of-the-each-widget-in-the-screen-without-source

So I am using Androidviewclient

Have followed below steps

1) Downloaded the Androidviewclient-master.zip

2) unzipped and edited the dump file in the AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools for the souce location

3) Set the Environment variable ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME and PYTHONPATH

4) When i execute as below in cmd

C:\Users\Lahir\Desktop\Automation\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools>monkeyrunner.bat C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump.py

Getting Error as below:-

Can't open specified script file
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE
-s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
-p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
-v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)

And also instead of dump.py if i run as dump as below

C:\Users\Lahir\Desktop\Automation\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools>monkeyrunner.bat C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump

I am getting the following Error

140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump", line 129, in 
    vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1), **kwargs2)
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1435, in connectToDeviceOrExit
    ViewClient.setAlarm(timeout+5)
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1395, in setAlarm
    signal.alarm(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Lahir\Desktop\Automation\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar\Lib\signal.py", line 222, in alarm

NotImplementedError: alarm not implemented on this platform

140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyException.doRaise(PyException.java:219)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1239)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1243)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1247)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at signal$py.alarm$14(C:\Users\Lahir\Desktop\Automation\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar\Lib\s
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at signal$py.call_function(C:\Users\Lahir\Desktop\Automation\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar\
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:134)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.**call**(PyFunction.java:317)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.setAlarm$71(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py:1395)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:134)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.**call**(PyFunction.java:317)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.connectToDeviceOrExit$72(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py:1463)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:301)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.function___call__(PyFunction.java:376)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.**call**(PyFunction.java:371)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.**call**(PyFunction.java:366)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyObject._callextra(PyObject.java:527)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump:131)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.core.**builtin**.execfile_flags(**builtin**.java:522)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:225)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:77)
140509 17:19:12.884:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:189)

Don't know how to get it? Need help please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you downloaded the latest version from github (.i.e. **AndroidViewClient 5.4.7**).
In such case, you don't need `monkeyrunner`, just `python`.

I think

```
python C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump.py
```

should work (sorry, I'm guessing as I don't use Windows).

You could also give `easy_install` a try and keep **AndroidViewClient** up-to-date automatically.
Check [How to use Python's "easy_install" on Windows ... it's not so easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016151/how-to-use-pythons-easy-install-on-windows-its-not-so-easy) for some hints.

Comment: Have already installed easy_install. About the version i have downloaded https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient. In dump file  verion shows as __version__ = '5.4.5'.

Comment: Hi Thank you its running as you said rather than monkeyrunner using only python i am able to get. Thank you :).                       But one issue after running i am getting the following output C:\Python27>python C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump
            android.widget.TextView  Hello ALLLL
            android.widget.Button com.example.pageindicator:id/gotoSurface Go to Surface
My doubt why i am not able to get the id for the Textview?? will i get the id for the Testview also

Comment: Ask another SO question to keep this organized

Comment: @dtmilano There is an AndroidViewClient 5.4.7??? All I can see on github is 5.1.1.

Comment: @dtmilano Oh wow. All I can find by just searching around is the older versions. But I upgraded with easy_install and now I got the 7.0.2. Is there a hangout where everyone talks about the latest stuff and has latest examples or some API? I assume github is outdated now?

Comment: Latest info about **AndroidViewClient/culebra** can be found at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/

Comment: @dtmilano this is a dumb question but what does dump.py actually do? When do you use it? (I read the docs on your main site and still don't get it)

Comment: dumps the content of the screen. See it as a *logical* screenshot.