# Not able to setup AndroidViewClient on Windows 7

Tags: android, androidviewclient

I referred to the [wiki](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki)  and tried over the internet but could not make it working.
I have set ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME to AndroidViewClient folder, PYTHONPATH to AndroidViewClient/src folder.

I am still not able to import the ViewClient and getting following exception on running the monkeyrunner script.

```
    from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
ImportError: No module named dtmilano

140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:304)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.import_logic(imp.java:790)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:842)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:917)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1011)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:987)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(c:\testing\demo.py:40)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(c:\testing\demo.py)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:522)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:225)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:77)
140910 18:18:23.594:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:189)
```

Can you anbybody suggest what am I missing?

Comment: Which *AndroidViewClient* version? Note that latest versions don't use jython or monkeyrunner.

Comment: I am using AndroidViewClient-5.1.1.
I followed your wiki (https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#verifying-environment-setup) but getting the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly recommended to use `easy_install` to install **AndroidViewClient**. However, it may not be clear how to do it on Windows, in such case you may find helpful the answers to [How to use Python's "easy_install" on Windows ... it's not so easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016151/how-to-use-pythons-easy-install-on-windows-its-not-so-easy).

Comment: Thanks. I opened the AndroidViewClient project in Python IDE and copied my test script in the examples folder. I am able to run the tests on my device. I'll try installing AndroidViewClient using easy_install and see if it can help me in running my scripts from anywhere.

Comment: Great. It should be a matter of specifying the correct PYTHONPATH, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: You're right. I got it working and able to run the script from anywhere.